# What is the best way to use ChangeNotifier provider objects with the build method?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

I have a flutter application and I keep getting the error which states:

```
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for UserData:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

UserData is a class that extends ChangeNotifier and this exception is thrown when I call the `notifyListeners()` method.

#### My View

```
class MyViewextends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyViewState createState() => _MyViewState();
}

class _MyViewState extends State<MyView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: UserService().getUser(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
            {
              var userData = Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false);
              var user = (snapshot.data as ApiResponseModel)?.entity;
              userData.set(user); //this is where the error gets thrown
            }

          return Container(); 
          //shortened for question purposes. Ideally, I will be printing the User objects to the container. 
          //It containers String properties like firstName, lastName.
        });
  }
}
```

#### UserData

```
class UserData extends ChangeNotifier{
  UserDto user;

  void set(UserDto userDto){
    user = userDto;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

What I want to know is, what better way can I initialise my UserDto object so this error is not thrown?

In my head, that `if` block made the most sense but apparently not.

Comment: What is above `MyView` in the widget tree? Is it possible that your `ChangeNotifier`  is listened by some widget above? Because in this case `userData.set(user)` can cause a rebuild. You can try: `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) { userData.set(user); });` instead of simply calling.

Comment: @PeterKoltai thanks it worked! Can you explain to me what this does please?

Comment: The error you got means that the widget is marked to be rebuilt during another build is in progress. The `addPostFrameCallback` executes the passed callback after the current build is completed, therefore eliminates to problem of duplicate builds at the same time.